# What does the underline that is automatically put under the end brace by IntelliSense brace completion denote?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

What does the underline that is automatically put under the end brace of a method by IntelliSense brace completion denote? I'm attaching an image to indicate what I'm talking about. Specifically, is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate to the underline while still being in the method block?

[image: Brace Underline]

To recreate the screenshot, create a method in VS 2015 and when you hit the open curly brace, both the curly braces show up. Hit enter and continue adding code including decision code blocks and the underline is still there. Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate to the underline without having to traverse through all the other lines of code?

This screenshot is from Visual Studio 2015 but I remember this being present in Visual Studio 2013 as well.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was about to answer this, but a search for a supporting link pulled up an existing question for this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did search for the same but wasn't able to find it.

Comment: The linked answer talks about "While in this mode, you can also press tab to move the cursor past the closing brace; although, this only seems to work when both braces are on the same line and there is nothing (except whitespace) between the cursor and the closing brace." Is there a way to move past the end brace in VS 2015 or later using some keyboard shortcut?